# Xamarin.Auth Facebook login Completed event not firing

Tags: facebook, xamarin.auth

I am trying to create a Xamarin.Forms application with a Facebook login button. Everything works up until the part where the `Completed` event, which never gets fired.

I am using a `PageRenderer` to initiate the auth flow as follows:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page1), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]
namespace xmrn1.Droid {
    class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer {
        private const string ClientId = "<sanitized>";

        public LoginPageRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e) {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var authorizeUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/");
            var redirectUri = new Uri($"fb{ClientId}://authorize");
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                ClientId,
                "email",
                authorizeUri,
                redirectUri);

            auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
            var ui = auth.GetUI(Context);
            Context.StartActivity(ui);
        }

        private void Auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e) {
            // This never gets called
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my "Facebook Login" settings:

[image: Imgur]

And my "Advanced Settings" settings:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I had to turn on the `Web OAuth Login` in the `Facebook Login` settings, and also to change the `redirectUri` to some uri in my domain, and add that uri to the `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` in that same settings window.

Strange thing though, now when I log in, and the two-factor-authentication code prompt shows up, my phone displays an authenticator popup notification asking me to approve and when I press "Yes" it doesn't automatically confirm the login, I have to manually type the 2fa code anyway...