# Xamarin Forms Facebook Authentication

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to use **OAuth Facebook Authentication** to login into my Xamarin.Forms application.

This is my athentication:

```
try
{
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: Constants.FacebookAndroidClientId,
                scope: "email",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

                auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
                auth.Error += Auth_Error;
                auth.BrowsingCompleted += Auth_BrowsingCompleted;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

But no event is firing. The authentication is created and nothing more happens.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: your are creating an auth client, but are you actually calling the Login method?

Answer (score 0):

You may missed some steps when using `Xamarin.Auth` to authenticate users, the code you shared is not enough. You also need to `Presenting the Sign-In User Interface` in specific platform and do some configurations.

Here is the document you can read: [Authenticate Users with an Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#using-xamarinauth-to-authenticate-users)

Here is the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth#11-create-and-configure-an-authenticator) of Xamarin.Auth, there are also detailed steps you can follow.

BTW, you should also be attention to your `Facebook Login settings` as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822377/xamarin-auth-facebook-login-completed-event-not-firing).